# How to request post to aspx site in python?

Tags: python, asp.net, request

This is the url I'm trying to parse.
url = 'https://www.ncsl.org/research/energy/energy-legislation-tracking-database.aspx'
I'm trying to select "all state" and "all topic" option, and retrieve the search output.

```
def Generate_params(tn=22, sn=55, searchyear=2008, vr=vrstring):
    topicstring = "dnn$ctr85406$StateNetDB$ckBxTopics$"
    statestring = 'dnn$ctr85406$StateNetDB$ckBxStates$'
    params = {}
    params['dnn$ctr85406$StateNetDB$ckBxAllTopics']='on'
    params['dnn$ctr85406$StateNetDB$ckBxAllStates']='on'
    for t in range(tn+1):
        topic_n = topicstring+"{}".format(t)
        params[topic_n]='on'
    for s in range(sn+1):
        state_n = statestring+"{}".format(s)
        params[state_n]='on'
    # vrstring is a string parameter I have outside the function. 
    params['__VIEWSTATE']=vrstring
    params['dnn$ctr85406$StateNetDB$ddlYear']=str(searchyear)
    params['dnn$ctr85406$StateNetDB$btnSearch']='Search'
    params['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']='CA0B0334'
    return params

from requests import Request, Session
post_params=Generate_params()
session = Session()
response = session.post(url, headers=headers,data=post_params)
```

But the returned response don't have the search output. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well spit out the whole URL as a string. Now fire up a fresh browser, and paste in that URL. does it work? I mean, paste the resulting url as a string in your above question. and try typing in that url that your code results in. If the URL don't work, then we missing a real whopper of a simple thing to try, right?

Comment: Thanks Albert, manual enter and retrieve the search does work. My question is how to parse it without copy/paste the browser content.

Comment: Did not quite say manual entry. I said take the resulting URL your code is creating, and paste that into a browser. Did that work? Looking at the web site, we see that the web application does not use nor have parameters in the URL.  So, not sure what you mean by manual enter, but the concept was what does your resulting code produce for a URL and does THAT work when pasted into a browser? Unless you can get your code to do the actual "clicks" in the browser, then it not practical to pass a URL with parameters when no parameters are being used, right?

Comment: Most asp.net applications have code behind written in c# or vb.net. We don't use much scripting and  the server side code is written as a .net application (which is rather easy to write - and you working with a full development system of .net. So one in asp.net tends to avoid parameters in the URL, and we don't really need them, and they tend to be rather messy anyway.  About the only way would be for client software to create a instance of the browser (say inside a form). You click/browse and get to the page you want, and THEN take that browser instance and pull data from the DOM.

Comment: yes, the url doesn't change. I was hoping to have a "post" method to do the selecting and clicking job. Anyway, I solve this by using selenium instead. Thanks anyway.